# How to make "line" go from left to right

Tags: r, plot

I am making some graphs using plot in r to look at SSB of Haddock with latitude of spawning but when i plot the two agains each other the line jumps back and forth crossing itself.

[image]

```r
plot(ICESuå$SSB, vd$lat, type="l", xlab = "Spawning stock biomass", ylab = "latitude")

data
ICESuå$SSB
[1]  95103 100769 118418 153491 171704 182526 177809 188665 213691 234729 338146
[12] 445077 539727 564781 556572 517746 492816 363474

vd$lat
[1] 68.44364 68.57394 68.05612 68.69964 69.19116 69.71899 69.90375 69.37346 69.93432
[10] 70.81535 70.66615 69.51964 70.47318 69.24921 68.90981 69.38605 70.28354 70.65420
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort based on the x-values (SSB)

```
SSB = c(95103, 100769, 118418, 153491, 171704, 182526, 177809, 
   188665, 213691, 234729, 338146,
   445077, 539727, 564781, 556572, 517746, 492816, 363474)

lat = c(68.44364, 68.57394, 68.05612, 68.69964, 69.19116, 
   69.71899, 69.90375, 69.37346, 69.93432,
   70.81535, 70.66615, 69.51964, 70.47318, 69.24921, 68.90981, 
   69.38605, 70.28354, 70.65420)

OrdSSB = order(SSB)
plot(SSB[OrdSSB], lat[OrdSSB], type="l", xlab = "Spawning stock biomass",
       ylab = "latitude")
```

[image: Plot with ordered values]

Answer (score 0):

If you convert to zoo then it will automatically sort the points:

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(data)
plot(z, xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
```

You can also easily convert that to ggplot2 like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

autoplot(z) + xlab("X") + ylab("Y")
```

### Note

The input used, shown in reproducible form is:

```
data <- data.frame(SSB = 
 c(95103, 100769, 118418, 153491, 171704, 182526, 177809, 188665, 213691, 234729,
 338146, 445077, 539727, 564781, 556572, 517746, 492816, 363474),
 lat = c(68.44364, 68.57394, 68.05612, 68.69964, 69.19116, 69.71899, 69.90375, 
 69.37346, 69.93432, 70.81535, 70.66615, 69.51964, 70.47318, 69.24921, 68.90981, 
 69.38605, 70.28354, 70.65420))
```